# Why does num_rows return 0 even when a row does exist in the database?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

When the below code is executed, num_rows always returns 0 even if the SQL statement should be fetching one result. I have confirmed that there is a token to select at the associated user_email, so what gives?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT token FROM users WHERE user_email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $_POST['email']);
confirmQuery($stmt);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
if($stmt->num_rows < 1) {
    echo(displayMessage("Token did not exist! Exiting program.","danger"));
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Check for errors in the execution.

Comment: I'm not getting any.

Comment: And how did you check for errors in php?

Comment: did you use [mysqli_error()](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_error.asp) or something to check?

Comment: Yes, that is what confirmQuery() does.

Comment: Try `$_POST['email'] = trim($_POST['email'])`, there's probably extra spaces around it.

Comment: then shouldnt  `confirmQuery()` be after  `$stmt->execute();`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Errors in `SELECT` statements would normally be detected when you're preparing it. If it prepares successfully, the query should succeed as well.

Comment: I moved it afterwards already, no change.

Comment: There's no reason why `num_rows` would return `0` if the query matched rows in the table. So the problem must be that `$_POST['email']` doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: Try `echo '<pre>';var_dump($_POST['email']); echo '</pre>';` to see what's in the parameter.

Comment: @Barmar I still wish he post the confirmQuery() code, But Solid, if the problem is the email parameter, try the same query without the `WHERE` to  confirm.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza If there were a problem with the query, `prepare()` would return `false`, so none of the `$stmt->anything` calls would work.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it myself. The problem was that I was sending via the get method, not post, so the $_POST['email'] was a mistake. The query must have been looking for rows where email was empty, but no rows like that exist, thus the 0 num rows.